# Benchmark performance of NIC IC 82574L on Debian 7.0

Tags: debian, networkcard

I figured out my NIC is an IC 82574L 1Gbit/s through ethernet by running `lshw -class network`.
Theoretically, this should allow me to transmit and receive packets at a rate of ~125MB/s (I don't need this for network reasons, but rather to transmit at 100MB/s through the Ethernet cable to another hardware piece).

My question is if there is a way to benchmark the highest, lowest and average **actual** rates at which my NIC at `eth1` is operating.

**Edit**: I've been able to show what I assume is the average rate with the following command

```
iperf -u -fM -t10 -c <my_devices_IP_address> -b 1G
```

The question now is it there another way to do a more detailed benchmark with minimums and maximums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `nload` and `iptraf` for that.

To test the max rate you can use hping3 to flood  the other side:

```
hping3  --flood -d 1460 ip
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example for UDP with my system? Assuming I want to benchmark the link between 192.168.20.1 and 192.168.20.2, and see if effectively the 1Gbitps is mantained or not (following NIC specs), what the min, max, etc is.

Comment: start nload in a terminal and run `hping3 --udp -d 1460 --flood 192.168.20.2`. nload show max/min/avg rates.